# Practical examples of NFA and epsilon NFA

Tags: automata

What are the real time examples of NFA and epsilon NFA i.e. practical examples other than that it is used in designing compilers

Answer (score 2):

Any time anyone uses a regular expression, they're using a finite automaton. And if you don't know a lot about regexes, let me tell you they're incredibly common -- in many ecosystems, it's the first tool most people try to apply when faced with getting structured data out of strings. Understanding automata is one way to understand (and reason about) regexes, and a quite viable one at that if you're mathematically inclined.

Actually, today's regex engines have grown beyond these mathematical concepts and added features that permit doing more than an FA allows. Nevertheless, many regexes don't use these features, or use them in such a limited way that it's feasible to implement them with FAs.

Now, I only spoke of finite automata in general before. An NFA is a specific FA, just like a DFA is, and the two can be converted into one another (technically, any DFA already is a NFA). So while you can just substitute "finite automaton" with "NFA" in the above, be aware that it doesn't have to be an NFA under the hood.

Comment: Please dont't make your own questions while answering, refer to the question asked

Comment: @west007 Did I do that? Please elaborate, because as far as I am concerned, I answered your question (as I understood it).

Answer (score 1):

And let's not forget [Markov chains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain) which are basically based on on finite automata as well. In combination with the hardware and sofware modelling that bellpeace mentioned, a very powerful tool.

If you are wondering why epsilon NFAs are considered a variation of NFAs, then I don't think there is a good reason. They are interpreted in the same way, except every step may not be a unit time anymore, but an NFA is that not really either.

Answer (score 0):

Like explained by @delnan, automatas are often used in the form of regular expressions. However, they are used a bit more than just that. Automatas are often used to model hardware and software systems and verifying their certain properties. You can find more information by looking at [model checking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_checking). One really really simplified motivating example can be found in the introduction of [Introduction to Automata, Languages, and Computation](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/ialc.html).

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat obscure but effective example would be [the aho-corasick algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm), which uses a finite automaton to search for multiple strings within text